# Xcode 7.1 crashing- libSwiftCore.dylib

Tags: ios, xcode

Updated to Xcode 7.1 today. Cannot open, due to a crash that says "Xcode quit unexpectedly while using the libswiftCore.dylib plug-in.

Stack trace:

```
Process:               Xcode [610]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.1 (9079)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-9079000000000000~8
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       813804225
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [610]
User ID:               502

PlugIn Path:             /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/libswiftCore.dylib
PlugIn Identifier:       libswiftCore.dylib
PlugIn Version:          2.1 (700.1.101.6)

Date/Time:             2015-10-23 17:33:26.756 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.1 (15B42)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        92906A5F-963D-4D90-6510-F624BB6F0130


Time Awake Since Boot: 350 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7B91b

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9a2fed32 strlen + 18
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001124f7aac _buildDemanglingForNominalType(swift::Demangle::Node::Kind, swift::Metadata const*, swift::NominalTypeDescriptor const*) + 44
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001124f5cc5 _buildDemanglingForMetadata(swift::Metadata const*) + 133
3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001124f7b7c _buildDemanglingForNominalType(swift::Demangle::Node::Kind, swift::Metadata const*, swift::NominalTypeDescriptor const*) + 252
4   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001124f5cc5 _buildDemanglingForMetadata(swift::Metadata const*) + 133
5   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001124f59bc swift_getGenericClassObjCName + 28
6   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001124475dd 0x1122ae000 + 1676765
7   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001124ebdd8 (anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry* llvm::function_ref<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry* ()>::callback_fn<swift::swift_getGenericMetadata::$_0>(long) + 24
8   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001124ebce0 swift::MetadataCache<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry>::addMetadataEntry(swift::EntryRef<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry>, ConcurrentList<swift::MetadataCache<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry>::EntryPair>&, llvm::function_ref<(anonymous namespace)::GenericCacheEntry* ()>) + 128
9   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001124e8488 swift_getGenericMetadata + 504
10  libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001124e851d swift_getGenericMetadata3 + 29
11  libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x00000001127c9226 _TZFe0_Rq_Ss8Hashable_10FoundationVSs10Dictionary26_forceBridgeFromObjectiveCu0_Rq_S__fMGS1_q_q0__FTCSo12NSDictionary6resultRGSqGS1_q_q0____T_ + 54
12  libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x00000001127c90ed _TF10Foundation32_convertNSDictionaryToDictionaryu0_Rq_Ss8Hashable_FGSqCSo12NSDictionary_GVSs10Dictionaryq_q0__ + 61
13  ca.nri.ColorSenseRainbow        0x000000011207e1ad _TTSf4g_n___TZFC17ColorSenseRainbow17ColorSenseRainbow13pluginDidLoadfMS0_FCSo8NSBundleT_ + 189 (ColorSenseRainbow.swift:33)
14  ca.nri.ColorSenseRainbow        0x000000011207c6f5 _TToZFC17ColorSenseRainbow17ColorSenseRainbow13pluginDidLoadfMS0_FCSo8NSBundleT_ + 37
15  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010ded1658 __46-[XCPluginManager loadPluginBundle:forDomain:]_block_invoke + 143
16  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001058ba9bc DVTInvokeWithFailureHint + 83
17  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010ded13c8 -[XCPluginManager loadPluginBundle:forDomain:] + 1054
18  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010ded0e5b __46-[XCPluginManager findAndLoadPluginsInDomain:]_block_invoke + 621
19  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001058a02c5 -[DVTPlugInManager _allowNonApplePlugInsFromDescriptors:error:] + 470
20  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001058a054d -[DVTPlugInManager _checkNonApplePlugIns] + 239
21  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001058a062e -[DVTPlugInManager initializePlugIns:] + 27
22  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x00000001063f1724 _IDEInitializeOtherPlugInStuff + 175
23  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x00000001063f2814 IDEInitialize + 3725
24  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000106aee2fc -[IDEApplicationController applicationWillFinishLaunching:] + 708
25  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d30cc9c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
26  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d30cc2f ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63
27  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d30cba7 _CFXRegistrationPost + 407
28  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d30c912 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
29  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d2c96d2 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1922
30  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d2c8925 _CFXNotificationPost + 693
31  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff97dc40fa -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
32  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000105892d45 -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 698
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91657022 -[NSApplication finishLaunching] + 354
34  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x0000000105e9349c -[DVTApplication finishLaunching] + 149
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91656b65 -[NSApplication run] + 231
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9161ffbe NSApplicationMain +     1176
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff938e75ad start + 1
```

Please help. Anyone else get this? I did have to update this again after the update bombed in the middle of the download, and I had to manually download the .dmg file from the dev portal. After wiping the machine clean of anything related to Xcode, I reinstalled from the App Store. Giving me this every time, even after a restart.

Comment: No problems with Xcode 7.1 here. I would create a question on the Apple Developer forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the ColorSenseRainbow plugin from:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plugin-ins
```

I'm looking into why it's causing Xcode to crash.

When it's fixed I'll post a note up at the GitHub site at https://github.com/NorthernRealities/ColorSenseRainbow

Comment: Thank you man!!! Good luck with your fix - I'll take a look myself and see if I can find anything.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I may have found it.  I wasn't unwrapping something properly when getting the bundle name (at least that's what I can tell from the stack trace above).  I can't recreate the problem on my machine.  I was wondering if you would be able to test my change if I sent it to you.  My email is Reid at nri dot ca.  I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: Hi.  I did find it thanks to your stack trace and it has now been tested and been committed to the main branch on GitHub.